# TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python-2.7, keras, softmax

When I use this it does not give any error

```
out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_4 , weights['out']) , biases['out'])
out_layer = tf.nn.softmax(out_layer)
```

But when I use this

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Dense(100, input_dim= n_dim, 
activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)

model.add(Dense(50,input_dim=1000,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None)

model.add(Dense(15,input_dim=500,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None)

model.add(Dense(units=n_class))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I get error as

> TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

What should I do?
I am using python2
Thanks

Comment: Upgrade, `pip install -U keras tensorflow`, it's likely you are using an old version.

Comment: I had to restart my notebook after the upgrade in order for the upgrade changes to take effect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Then add a softmax layer in this way:

```
model.add(Activation(tf.nn.softmax))
```

Comment: @SAEERON Hey it works for me, but when I try to save the model and load it, I got the same error:
TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. 
My env is: OSX, keras=2.1.6, tf=1.1.0

Comment: What is the equivalent of `model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))`? i.e. how do you use your syntax (`model.add(Activation(tf.nn.softmax))`) for multi-class output?

Answer (score 7):

Upgrade your tensoflow and Keras libraries to latest versions. Lower versions don't support softmax axis.
Make sure you are upgrading them in the environment in which you are running the program (very important).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why assert this error is version of tensorflow and keras is mismatch. I have slove this problem:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5.0
```

If you donot want to downdegree keras, tf 1.5.0 is the first version that support softmax(axis=axis).

Answer (score 0):

upgrade tensorflow and keras to below version solved my issue

```
pip install keras==2.1.6
pip install tensorflow==1.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too had the same problem,

by updating the package in anaconda

and model.add(Activation(tf.nn.softmax)) works fine.

Comment: Please complete your answer and provide the necessary commands for updating the package.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install TensorFlow. You can do it using one of the following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow      # for Python 2.7
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```